# calling a method with signature

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method with a signautre in rails:

```
def my_function(some_variable)

end
```

I call the method from jquery get function like this:

```
$.get('/controller/my_function', {data: mydata}, function(){

    });
```

But I get an error because I need to send the argument also.
How can I do that?

Comment: jquery call is an http request not a function call. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an action in your controller and call your function from that action

```
def my_action
  my_function(params[:data])
end
```

and your jquery script will be calling my_action

```
$.get('/controller/my_action', {data: mydata}, function(){

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Henry pointed out - in your javascript code `data: xxxx` is HTTP parameters being sent from the browser to your rails controller action on the server, rails puts all HTTP parameters into the `params` hash, so if you had

```
var data = {
  first_name: "Joe",
  last_name: "Smith"
}
$.get('/controller/some_action', data, function() {
  // ...
```

access those in the params hash on the server

```
def some_action
  logger.debug params.inspect
  # => { :first_name => "Joe", :last_name => "Smith", :action => "some_action" }

  user.first_name = params[:first_name]
  # ...
end
```